# Add UIImage and Segmented Control to Navigation Bar Center

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to add both an UIImage AND an UISegmentedControl to the middle of the navigation bar.

I can successfully set one of them to the middle of the nav bar with

```
 [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:segmentedControl];
```

But only one of them can be displayed using setTitleView. Is there anyway to add the UIImage maybe as a subview IN ADDITION to the segmented control? For example, here is my not-working code to try to add two uielements onto the center of the tab bar.

```
UIImageView *logoImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];


logoImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segControlIcon.png"];
[[self navigationItem] setTitleView:logoImage];


UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [NSString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"One", @"")],
                                         [NSString stringWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Two", @"")],
                                         nil]];


[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];


[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSearchType:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];



[segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,35)];

[[self navigationItem] setTitleView:segmentedControl];
```

Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you could add both to a `UIToolbar`, then set the `UIToolbar` as the `TitleView`

Comment: Create a `UIView` and then add the image view and the segmented control to the view. Then make the view the title's view.

Comment: I tried `UIView *segControlView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    
    [segControlView addSubview:logoImage];
    [segControlView addSubview:segmentedControl];
    
    [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:segControlView];` and it only shows the segcontrol

Comment: Never mind; using UIView works. If you want to put it in a answer I'll accept it

Comment: @rmaddy visual wise, it works, but I can't seem to tap the segmentedcontrol. It's not responsive. Any idea why?

Comment: Make sure nothing is covering the segmented control and make sure it is actually within the bounds of its superview. As a test, set the view's background color to yellow or something obvious.

Comment: @rmaddy I created the UIView exactly what is in my comment above. I tried `[segControlView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];` and nothing yellow appears

Comment: Oops. forgot to initWithFrame for UIView. Now the frame I specified appears yellow, and it works. Thanks.